# Найти пропущенное число js

Tags: javascript

Искал по поиску но так и не нашел конкретного способа.
Распишите, пожалуйста.

Есть массив

`mass=[4,5,2,9,20,14]`.

Как мне найти пропущенные числа?

Пробовал и циклом проходиться, и через `forEach`, но вот просто  не могу понять сам принцип. Что мне нужно сделать что бы найти его.
Пробовал проверять в цикле, соответствует ли каждый элемент массива числу от `0` до `mass.length`, и если не соответствует то значит его в массиве нет. Но все равно не смог это нормально реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Сортируете исходный массив
2. Берёте первый и последний элемент, заносите в переменные min и max

Можно воспользоваться `Math.min()` и `Math.max()` вместо первых двух пунктов. Как аргумент передав массив в формате rest  `...mass`

А можно и за один проход цикла найти сразу и минимум и максимум, не используя остальные функции и не сортируя.

В общем суть пока найти минимум и максимум в массиве.

3. Генерируете новый массив от минимального (min) до максимального (max) числа. Хоть через цикл, хоть любыми функциями
4. C помощью метода [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) исключаете из второго массива числа, которые есть в первом массиве, используя например метод [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Вместо 3, 4 пункта можно создать новый массив, сделать один цикл от минимума до максимума с шагом 1, где проверить, входит ли `i` в массив `mass` (с помощью `includes`) и если не входит, то сделать добавление числа в новый массив

Comment: Мне кажтеся, кодом было бы понятнее) И меньше текста)

Comment: @Дмытрык А мне кажется мы тут не решаем за других, иначе люди думать разучатся)

Comment: Для того что бы разучиться нужно сначала научиться. Но здесь учить не хотят, здесь людям важнее свое ЧСВ поднять за счет новичков.

Comment: @Виталий учатся на практике. Практика - это когда ты почитал несколько книг по языку, учишься логически думать, разбить задачу на мелкие,  написать алгоритм выполнения, попробовать раз, другой, третий написать код.  А прийти просто за кодом - это не учиться. Это просто взять и не думать. Ну и по факту - что из того, что написано не ясно? Вы не умеете писать цикл? Тогда вам надо изучать основы. Не умеете находить минимум и максимум? Тогда вам надо опять книжку по основам почитать для развития логики. Непонятно как работают перечисленные методы? В документации написано. Или читать лень?

Comment: @Виталий вам предоставлен полный список всевозможных функций, которыми можно воспользоваться, написан алгоритм ЗА ВАС и альтернативные варианты его исполнения. **Полностью** от и до.. Написано куда можно смотреть для примеров работы методов. Если вы этим не можете воспользоваться - тогда у меня для вас плохие новости

Answer (score 0):

Когда не знаешь хороший ли код написал делай:

1. Смотреть в сторону [прототипов объектов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) (слева) и в голове цикл: `if(подходит мне)`
2. Когда уже имеешь два кода, [нажми сюда](https://jsbench.me/) и сравнивай (еще важный параметр сравнения - handling, а т.е. удобно ли тебе содержать этот цикл)

Мой вариант решения

```js
const getMissed=(arr)=>{
    // сортируем, чтоб узнать наибольшее число
    arr = arr.sort((a,b)=>(a-b));
    // создаем пустой массив по наибольшему и заполняем чем-нибудь
    let missed = new Array(arr[arr.length-1]+1).fill(0);
    
    // удаляем ноль, можешь убрать
    delete missed[0];
    for(let a of arr){
        // удаляем числа, которые есть
        delete missed[a];
    }
    
    // возвращаем индексы без удаленных чисел
    return Object.keys(missed);
};

const mass = [4, 5, 2, 9, 20, 14];
const miss = getMissed(mass);

console.log(mass);
console.log(miss, miss.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу.

```
function findNumber(array) {
   var result =[];

for(var i =0;i <= Math.max.apply(null, array); i++){
   if( !array.includes(i) ){
      result.push(i);
   }
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Решение:

```
var mass_1 = [3, 4, 6, 1];
var mass_sort = mass_1.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var mass_3 = [];
var set_result = new Set();

for (var i = 0; i <= Math.max.apply(null, mass_sort); i++) {
  mass_3.push(i);
}

for (var i = 0; i <= Math.max.apply(null, mass_3); i++) {
  if (mass_sort.includes(mass_3[i]) === false) {
    set_result.add(mass_3[i]);
  }
}
console.log("Массив 2: " + mass_sort);
console.log("Массив 3: " + mass_3);
console.log(set_result);
```

Comment: Твое решение не работает, потому что не объявлена переменная `mass_2`